# How do I configure wkhtmltopdf to request https pages by URL not IP on Windows 8.1?

Tags: https, dns, wkhtmltopdf, prefetch

Does anybody know how I can make wkhtmltopdf request https pages by URL, not IP?

I am using wkhtmltopdf (& wkhtmltoimage) to capture web pages. As part of this I want to capture the URL of the page requested. I have been passing the request through Fiddler and all is working fine, except that whenever wkhtmltopdf requests an https link, it uses the IP address, rather than the URL.

Is there a way to ensure the request uses the URL rather than the IP?

I thought that wkhtmltopdf was getting the IP from the DNS cache, so I have cleared the cache and disabled it, but it still requests by IP, not URL.

I suspect this may be a result of DNS prefetching by wkhtmltopdf, but it only happens for HTTPS requests. HTTP requests all come through as URL, which is what I want.

Does anybody know how I can make wkhtmltopdf request https pages by URL, not IP?

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this issue? I'm having the same problem :( Works fine on http:// but https:// fails

Comment: I am also having the same issue whilst generating a PDF file from a pre-prepared static html file.  The PDF file is generated ok but with no images and styled headings The images and css files are ignored because the server requires an https connection.